# Reference Higher-Level Directories

Tags: python, directory, pathlib

To reference Higher-Level directories with `os` something like this `'../../mydir'` could work but I do not prefer `os.path`. Instead I prefer pathlib.

This is which would work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('.').absolute().parent.parent / Path('mydir')
```

This looks more complex then just `'../../mydir'`

Is there a similar way in pathlib to create this behaviour?

Comment: How about `path = Path('../../mydir').resolve()` ?

Comment: That is the behaviour I expected.